# UML Annotation >>

Tags: visual-studio, uml, tool-uml

I have a Model in UML of visual studio and between two entities A  y B are a --->>. I mean the Model has     A --->> B

What does it mean?

Sorry for not paste a image, the problem is I am new in stack and yet I can"t post images with my reputation.

Comment: If you put your image on a public image hosting site and add a link to it, there's usually a helpful person that integrates it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notation does not exist in UML.

It might mean something in another notation, but then of course it would be helpful to know which one.

Answer (score 0):

Was it like this ?
[image]

If so, it means that class A has a data member (a) which is of type B.
This is a simple association relationship such that an object of type A refers to an object of type B using a variable 'a'

If the head of the arrow was hollow, it means A is a subtype of B.
If the line connecting A and B is dashed, it means class A implements interface B. 
...etc.

UML is a pretty exacting graphical format, so the small details may make big differences in meaning.

It might be better if you can get a picture and upload it, then we can help you with the meaning.

Comment: That arrow is not UML. You either have an open arrow head, or a closed one, but never this in-between form.